Set the current line limit for jumping in Vim
I want to set a limit for the use of e. Basically e is for jumping forward to the end of words, but I do not want to go to the next line. I just want to jump to the end of all the words in the current line and finally stop at the end of the current line. How can we write a function for this in lua for Neovim?

Why not use $ to jump directly to the last character in the line?

This might be doable by changing whichwrap

@wxz I want to combine them.
